# Springboot executable jar can not access index page

Tags: java, angularjs, maven, spring-boot, jar

I created an application with springboot, restapi and angularjs. I will turn this project as executable jar. but when i do `java -jar patchinit.jar`, it does not reload index page. it gives

> Whitelabel Error Page (There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found,
>   status=404 No message available)

Trying to **http://localhost:8080/**

Am i missing something? I almost tried everything desperately..

**POM.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.ama.ist</groupId>
    <artifactId>patchinit</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <name>patchinit Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>


    <properties>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
<!--            <scope>provided</scope> -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.tmatesoft.svnkit</groupId>
            <artifactId>svnkit</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.8</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>patchinit</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Webapplication.java**

```
package com.ama.ist;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@SpringBootApplication
public class WebApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(WebApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(WebApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**HelloController.java**

```
package com.ama.ist.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    String index() {
        return "index";
    }

}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MyApp">
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.5/angular-material.min.css">



</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-4 jumbotron">
                <div class="col-md-12 dialog-demo-content">
                    <div ui-view="newPatch"></div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="col-md-8 ">

                <div ui-view="svntab"></div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>



    <!--    <div class="container" class="md-padding" ng-cloak> -->
    <!--        <div class="row"> -->
    <!--            <div class="col-md-3 dialog-demo-content"> -->
    <!--                <div ui-view="newPatch"></div> -->
    <!--            </div> -->

    <!--            <div class="col-md-2"></div> -->



    <!--            <div class="col-md-3"> -->
    <!--                <div ui-view="svntab"></div> -->
    <!--            </div> -->
    <!--        </div> -->
    <!--    </div> -->




    <!-- *************************   SCRIPTS  ********************************** -->
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.8/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

    <script
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script
        src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">

    </script>
    <script
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
    <script
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>


    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/patch.controller.js"></script>
    <script src="js/svn.controller.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

**This is the output of springboot**

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.5.RELEASE)

2017-12-05 19:54:09.019  INFO 480 --- [           main] com.ama.ist.WebApplication               : Starting WebApplication on ISTL55310 with PID 480 (C:\Erkan\eclipse-workspace-new\patchinit\target\classes started by erkan.erkisi in C:\Erkan\eclipse-workspace-new\patchinit)
2017-12-05 19:54:09.022  INFO 480 --- [           main] com.ama.ist.WebApplication               : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-12-05 19:54:09.063  INFO 480 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1ce2a846: startup date [Tue Dec 05 19:54:09 EET 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-12-05 19:54:10.335  INFO 480 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-12-05 19:54:10.345  INFO 480 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2017-12-05 19:54:10.347  INFO 480 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.33
2017-12-05 19:54:10.987  INFO 480 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner     : At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2017-12-05 19:54:10.994  INFO 480 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-12-05 19:54:10.994  INFO 480 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1933 ms
2017-12-05 19:54:11.468  INFO 480 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-12-05 19:54:11.471  INFO 480 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-12-05 19:54:11.471  INFO 480 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-12-05 19:54:11.471  INFO 480 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-12-05 19:54:11.471  INFO 480 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-12-05 19:54:11.639  INFO 480 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1ce2a846: startup date [Tue Dec 05 19:54:09 EET 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-12-05 19:54:11.697  INFO 480 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/]}" onto java.lang.String com.ama.ist.controller.HelloController.index()
2017-12-05 19:54:11.698  INFO 480 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/resource]}" onto public java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object> com.ama.ist.controller.PatchController.home()
2017-12-05 19:54:11.698  INFO 480 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/mk],methods=[POST]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> com.ama.ist.controller.PatchController.createFolder(com.ama.ist.model.Patch)
2017-12-05 19:54:11.701  INFO 480 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/localfolders],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.List<com.ama.ist.model.Folder>> com.ama.ist.controller.SvnController.getlocalFolders(com.ama.ist.model.User)
2017-12-05 19:54:11.702  INFO 480 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/svnfolders],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.List<com.ama.ist.model.Folder>> com.ama.ist.controller.SvnController.getFolders(com.ama.ist.model.User)
2017-12-05 19:54:11.703  INFO 480 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2017-12-05 19:54:11.704  INFO 480 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2017-12-05 19:54:11.716  INFO 480 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.c.a.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter      : Adding welcome page: ServletContext resource [/index.html]
2017-12-05 19:54:11.736  INFO 480 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Root mapping to handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController]
2017-12-05 19:54:11.745  INFO 480 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-12-05 19:54:11.745  INFO 480 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-12-05 19:54:11.778  INFO 480 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-12-05 19:54:11.878  INFO 480 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-12-05 19:54:11.945  INFO 480 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-12-05 19:54:11.949  INFO 480 --- [           main] com.ama.ist.WebApplication               : Started WebApplication in 3.254 seconds (JVM running for 3.827)
```

[Project Structure as an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRWWR.png)

Comment: I tried before but no luck :(

Comment: tried but not worked

Comment: hi, did you check the below solution

Comment: I will try in 2 hours and inform you

Comment: it is worked but also i have moved just index.hmtl file to resource/templates, rest of html pages to resource/static. I've created js folder in static folder and moved to js files in it. Thank you.                                                                 But why webapp folder did not worked? why we moved html and js files to templates. When you run on ide (eclipse) it was working as well with webapp folder structure

Comment: Erkisi : np mate

Comment: It will help you http://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-in-spring-mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got a solution. I was able to resolve this issue by adding `thymeleaf` dependency in pom

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**What is Thymeleaf?**

`Thymeleaf` is a Java library. It is an `XML/XHTML/HTML5` template engine that is able to apply a set of transformations to template files in order to display data and/or text produced by your applications.

There is one correction required in your html file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.5/angular-material.min.css">
```

make sure to close this tag `<link>` with end tag `</link>`. Otherwise you will get below error

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error,
>   status=500). Exception parsing document: template="index", line 12 -
>   column 3

**Project structure**

[image]